# Python discord bot disconnect() function not working

Tags: python, discord, disconnect

So I'm coding a discord bot in Python3.7 using the new discord.py rewrite and I've come across a snag in regards to the `disconnect()` function called on a `VoiceClient`

My code is as follows:

```
@bot.command()
async def leave(ctx):
    if ctx.author.voice is None:
        await ctx.send("Im not in a channel ")
        return
    await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()
```

It's a very simple command using the command extension of discord.py and the line `await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()` doesn't seem to want to work.

- There are no errors thrown when running
- I've put a debug `print("test")` directly after the `disconnect()` line and it printed
- I've checked all over the API's and I can't find anything that has worked so far
- The bot is able to join the channel perfectly fine
- Yes, this `leave` command function *is* being called
- Even the check before (`if ctx.author.voice is None:`) runs when the conditions are met to do so

Any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!
The correct libraries were not installed and used in the IDE.
Libraries found here: [discord.py Introduction - Libraries](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html)